# Coding a language translator

Tags: python

im trying to code a kind of language translator from any language to a kind of gibberish language, wheres every consonant will be replaced with the same consonant plus an o and then the consonant again.

```
b = bob
d = dod
f = fof
```

so the text "Hi my name is x" 
will become "Hohi momy nonamome isos xox"

The problem i have is the converting part.

any tips on how i can proceed?

Oh and btw I am using python 3

What i got this far.

```
#Welcom text
print ("Gibberish translator!")

#get stentence
original = raw_input("Give a sentence: ")

#Check so that it is a correct sentence
if len(original) > 0:
    print ("")
else:
    print ("give a real sentence..: ")

#convert
gibberish = ""
for i in original:
    if i == "b,c,d,f,g,h,j,k,l,m,n,p,q,r,s,t,v,w,x,z":
        i = i + "0" + i
        gibberish.append(i)
    elif i == "a,o,u,e,i,y":
        gibberish.append(i)

#print out the gibberish
print (gibberish)
```

Yeah! i think i got it to work quite well..

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
#Repeat
while True :
    #Welcom text
    print ("Gibberish translator!")

    #get stentence
    original = raw_input("Give a sentence: ")

    #Check so that it is a correct sentence
    if len(original) > 0:
        print ("")
    else:
        print ("Give a real sentence..: ")

    #convert
    gibberish = ""
    for i in original:
        if i in "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXZ":
            i = i + "o" + i
            gibberish = gibberish + i
        elif i in "aoueiyåäö AOUEIYÅÄÖ":
            gibberish = gibberish + i

    #print out the gibberish
    print (gibberish)
    print ("\n")
```

Im open for suggestions to make it "better"

Comment: What have you attempted so far? Where are you getting an error? This is not a site for people that won't try for themselves.

Comment: Oh sorry, this is my first post. I have eddited my post

Comment: Well, your code it's good, almost enough... but: you want `gibberish` to be a string, starting with an empty string, and later you try to `.append` characters to it. This is not going to work! `.append` is a method of lists, not strings, to put together two strings you'd simply use `+`, as in `gibberish=gibberish+i` but you already knew, I can see that by the line `i = i + "0" + i`  While we are at it, it's `"o"` not `"0"`.

Comment: If you get a working code, feel free to post it as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Yea! i cheak it out! @gboffi

Comment: By the way @FelixRosén, asking for suggestions to improve should be brought over to [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), the stackexchange site for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're comparing a character `i` to a string `"b,c,d,f,g,h,j,k,l,m,n,p,q,r,s,t,v,w,x,z"`. The two will never be equal.

What you want to do instead is use the `in` operator.

```
    if i in 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz':
```

Also, strings don't have an `.append()` method, only lists do.
You can create a string from a list of strings by doing `''.join(my_list)`

Comment: Ooops, I missed the mistake with the comparison in my comment to the question, upvote

Answer (score 0):

If and in statements don't work like that. This is actually a very common mistake, so no worries. When you get to the `if i == "b,c,d,f,g,h,j,k,l,m,n,p,q,r,s,t,v,w,x,z":` python reads that as "if i is all of this string (the string that contains all the consonants). Now unless you enter that string exactly somewhere in your sentence, python is going to think "nope no string like that" and skip it. You have the same problem with your vowel statements.

For the fastest fix:

```
if i in "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz": #note the removal of commas, don't want them getting "o'd"
    #rest of your code for consonants
else: #having an else is often very good practice, or else you may not get a result.
    #what to do if its not a consonant
```

The function checks if it is a lower case vowel (might want to add stuff for upper case letters), then if it isn't, it checks if it is a letter period. string is very useful when working with strings. You should [look at the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html).

And finally, you need to change append to just use `+` with strings.

Comment: Hi! Thx man! What i did now was to remove the append and instead gibberish += gibberish + i (where i is equal to i = i + "o" + i) but i cant quite get it to work.. Should i edit my original code to the current one?

Comment: Heeeyy! i got it to work! But only if u use small letters.. I guess i have to use the .uppercase() syntax. Any tips on how to do it to get the uppercases in the right possition?

Comment: nvm check out my original post i think i got it quite right!